# No known conditions for "./standalone" entry in "@firebase/database-compat" package

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, svelte, sveltekit

When running `npm run build` on my sveltekit project, i get the following error generated by `vite`:

```
7:55:49 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] The following packages did not export their `package.json` file so we could not check the "svelte" field. If you had difficulties importing svelte components from a package, then please contact the author and ask them to export the package.json file.
- firebase-admin
✓ 47 modules transformed.
[commonjs] No known conditions for "./standalone" entry in "@firebase/database-compat" package
> No known conditions for "./standalone" entry in "@firebase/database-compat" package
Error: No known conditions for "./standalone" entry in "@firebase/database-compat" package
    at bail (/home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:29712:8)
    at resolve$1 (/home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:29768:32)
    at resolveExports (/home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:30285:12)
    at resolveDeepImport (/home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:30301:26)
    at tryNodeResolve (/home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:30043:11)
    at Object.resolveId (/home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:29910:28)
    at /home/vincent/repos/sveltekit/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22697:251
```

I checked in the `node_modules` and the package `@firebase/database-compat` actually exports his package.json. I'm really stuck here.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build --verbose",
    "preview": "svelte-kit preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "next",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.39.2",
    "svelte": "^3.38.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "firebase": "^9.4.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.3.1",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "none"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this as I'm seeing it also.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the import from CJS style to ESM style.

From: `const { Pkg } = require('package/sub')`

To: `import { Pkg } from 'package/sub'`

Perhaps Vite just isn't able to resolve the way this package is exported and imported in this case?