# How do I fix a "no known conditions for "." entry" error from vite:dep-scan?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, vite

> Similar to [No known conditions for "./standalone" entry in "@firebase/database-compat" package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947875/no-known-conditions-for-standalone-entry-in-firebase-database-compat-pack) but I already using ESM modules (in fact I am not using CommonJS at all)

I am working on an npm module containing a Svelte component, with the following `package.json`, prepared per [the Svelte packaging documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging#anatomy-of-a-package-json-exports):

```
{
  "name": "@someorg/name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "svelte": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  }
}
```

The files `dist/index.d.ts` and `./dist/index.js` exist in the package after building.

When a third party project installs my module via `npm i`, importing works, eg:

```
import { AComponent, test } from '@someorg/name';
```

Has no errors in VSCode.

**However when I run `vite dev`**, I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-scan] Failed to resolve entry for package "@someorg/name". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: No known conditions for "." entry in "@someorg/name" package
```

I understand the error - something is wrong with `exports[.]` in `package.json`. But my two entries `types` and `svelte` are correct per the [Svelte documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging#anatomy-of-a-package-json-exports) and I don't know what the 'known' conditions are (and searching doesn't find a defintion).

```
{
  "name": "@someorg/name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "svelte": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answering my own question to help others.*

I suspect this is a vite version 3 issue.

**Upgrading from `vite` 3 to `vite` 4 fixed the issue** - `vite dev` no longer throws an error. I also updated `@sveltejs/kit` and `@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill` to handle dependencies, and had to update my route file names and svelte config as a result.